# How to disconnect my power LED connector?

Tags: case, connector

The Power LED of my BeQuite Silent Base 800 is connected with these connectors:

front (notice the little know probably closing the connection):
[image]

back (blank):
[image]

bottom (notice that the thing on the front that looks like a retention clip isn't one afaik):
[image]

There's no way of telling how to disconnect them. Nothing moves or is somehow flexible and the part is so small that I have to pull on the cables after trying to find eventual pressure points - consequently thoughtlessly.

The bottom part is most likely not a retention clip (I'll try to do another photo, but these blurry one are the best out of 20). The connection is certainly retained with the two knobs you can see on the first image.

I think it's very unlikely that the connection is permanent/not supposed to be disconnected by hand, but a producer like BeQuiet that fails to describe how to remove the top cover from the case in the manual, can easily fail at everything.

No idea why a relatively high quality case needs to use those connectors to save two cents and make me think.

Comment: It looks like there is a retention clip on your first picture. Squeeze the retention clip and pull apart.

Comment: Maybe the retention clip has to be lifted instead of squeezed, but the blur in the picture doesn't allow to really tell it, but it should be quite guessable in real view what to do to the clip to free the connector.

Comment: @davidmneedham I added images of the bottom which show imo that there's no rentention clip. The connection seems to be hold with the knobs noticable on the front image that I can't get a good image of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These simply pull apart, but they can be quite tight.
Don't pull on the wires. The unplugging may take more force than the tensile strength of the wires.
Hold the larger (bottom part in your pics) with pliers and pull on the ridges of the smaller (upper) part. To get enough grip on the upper part use your nails under the side-ridges at the top or use a 2nd set of pliers.
The vertical ridge in the middle shown on the upper pic might be a retention clip that needs to be pushed in or pried open a little bit (hard to tell from the pic). But I don't think so. These usually don't have retention clips at all.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's hard to make the pictures. I'm pretty sure that there's no retention clip - I'll try to make a better image. I'm sure that the connection is retained with the two knobs you can see/guess on the first image. How can I get past them? I just tried to disconnect them with two pliers and pull without involving the wires, but the material is soft as butter and both the pulling and the pressing causes damage.